# How to split the table with different number of columns into those with equal number of columns?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table

Consider the following table:

```
tab = Join[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4}], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 3}]]
```

Could you please tell me how to obtain the list of its sub-tables that have equal number of columns?

I.e.

```
listtab = {RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}],RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 3}],RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4}]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
tbl = Join[RandomInteger[5, {2, 2}],
  RandomInteger[5, {3, 4}],
  RandomInteger[5, {2, 3}]]
```

> ```
>  {{4, 2}, {4, 0},
>   {1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 5}, {2, 0, 3, 4}, 
>   {4, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 1}}
> ```

You can use [`SplitBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html)

```
SplitBy[tbl, Length]
```

> ```
>  {{{4, 2}, {4, 0}}, 
>   {{1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 5}, {2, 0, 3, 4}},
>   {{4, 1,3}, {3, 4, 1}}}
> ```

If the input is not already sorted by length as in

```
SeedRandom[1];
tbl2 = RandomSample[tbl]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 2}, {4, 1, 3}, 
>  {4, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 5}, {4, 0}}
> ```

you can sort it before applying `SplitBy`

```
SplitBy[SortBy[{Length}]@tbl2, Length]
```

> ```
>  {{{4, 2}, {4, 0}}, 
>  {{3, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 3}}, 
>  {{2, 0, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 5}}}
> ```

If the output need not be sorted, you can also use [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html):

```
GatherBy[tbl2, Length]
```

> ```
>  {{{3, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 3}}, 
>   {{2, 0, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 5}}, 
>   {{4, 2}, {4, 0}}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

```
Values @ GroupBy[Length] @ tbl2
```

> ```
>  {{{3, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 3}}, 
>   {{2, 0, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 5}}, 
>   {{4, 2}, {4, 0}}}
> ```

> 

Comment: Thanks! When applying `SplitBy` to the table `Join[RandomReal[{2,2},{2,2}],RandomReal[{2,2},{2,3}],RandomReal[{2,2},{2,2}]]`, it returns 3 tables instead of 2. Namely, it treats the two 2-column tables separated by the 3-column tables as the tables of different lengths. Could you please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: However, if the functionality of `GatherBy` and `GroupBy` is the same as the one of `SplitBy`, then this is not important, as the former do things properly.

Comment: if the input list is not sorted by length, you need sort it first before applying `SplitBy`, that is, you need to use `SplitBy[SortBy[{Length}]@tbl3, Length]` . (`GatherBy` and `GroupBy` work without pre-sorting)